# unable to display data in grid using xml

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to display a data based on xml in jqGrid. I use jqGrid in many places in my grid and it works with my earlier xml data.

The only difference is in xml. Current xml contains different tags.

```js
$("#uxData").jqGrid({
        url: ServiceUrl,
        datatype: 'xml',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['CardCode'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'CardCode', index: 'CardCode', sortable: true, align: "left", width: 100, search: true }
        ],
        loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $(this).HideBusy();
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
        loadComplete: function (data) {
            $("#Window").dialog('open');
            $(this).HideBusy();
            debugger;
        },
        serializeGridData: function (postData) {
            if (postData.searchField === undefined) postData.searchField = null;
            if (postData.searchString === undefined) postData.searchString = null;
            if (postData.searchOper === undefined) postData.searchOper = null;
            if (postData.filters === undefined) postData.filters = null;
            return (postData);
        },
        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
            //debugger;
            //var SelectedRow = $("#ListOfBP1").jqGrid('getRowData', rowid, 'selrow');

            //$("#uxCardCode").val(SelectedRow.CardCode);
            //$("#Text4").val(SelectedRow.CardName);
            $("#Window").dialog('close');
        },
        xmlReader: {
             repeatitems: false,
             total: "Root>total",
             page: "Root>page",
             records: "Root>records",
             rows: "Root>rows>DocumentElement>data"
        },
        pager: 'rptParamPager',
        rowNum: 5,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        height: 440,
        width: 900
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

```html
<Root>
    <total>161</total>
    <page>1</page>
    <records>805</records>
    <rows>
        <DocumentElement>
            <data>
                <CardCode>a</CardCode>
                <CardName>aasas as</CardName>
                <CardType>C</CardType>
                <Balance>0.000000</Balance>
            </data>
            <data>
                <CardCode>A0001</CardCode>
                <CardName>Manish Chourasia</CardName>
                <CardType>C</CardType>
                <Balance>100000.000000</Balance>
            </data>
            <data>
                <CardCode>A0002</CardCode>
                <CardName>Manish Chourasia</CardName>
                <CardType>C</CardType>
                <Balance>568368.000000</Balance>
            </data>
            <data>
                <CardCode>A0003</CardCode>
                <CardName>Vivek</CardName>
                <CardType>C</CardType>
                <Balance>0.000000</Balance>
            </data>
            <data>
                <CardCode>A00034</CardCode>
                <CardName>TUSHAR NATHWANI</CardName>
                <CardType>C</CardType>
                <Balance>0.000000</Balance>
            </data>
        </DocumentElement>
    </rows>
</Root>
```

I tried a lot to tweak xmlReader but does not work. I am completely confused with the behavior of xmlReader.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the `xmlReader` to the following:

```
xmlReader: {
     repeatitems: false,
     total: "Root>total",
     page: "Root>page",
     records: "Root>records",
     root: "Root>rows>DocumentElement",
     row: "data"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I tried this also, but still its not working, do I need to specify contentType

Comment: Is it possible to check in jqGrid source code? if yes, How do I debug the jqGrid script

Comment: @Manish: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/Manish.htm). It uses practically your code and only fixed `xmlReader`. I saved the XML data in file. You can see that it's enough.

Comment: @leg: Thanks your demo is working and the same snippet is not working at my place, can you please let me know to debug the script, where I can find out where the xml data is pull in jqGrid and creating <tr>

Comment: In fact the same type of snippet is working in my another screens, I don't understand why it is not working in this screen

Comment: Once again thanks for your support, I am able to debug jqGrid and found that problem is not from jqGrid snippet. it is from my web service . My service returning xml as string instead of XmlDocument. Once again THANKS IN TONS.